# How to labeling data in pandas based on value of column have similar value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, similarity

If there is someone who understands, please help me to resolve this. I want to label user data using python pandas, where there are two columns in my dataset, namely author, and retweeted_screen_name. I want to do a label with the criteria if every user in the author column has the same value in the retweeted_screen_name column then are 1 and the others that do not have the same value are 0.

| Author | RT_Screen_Name | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | John | 1 |
| Sandy | John | 1 |
| Lisa | Mario | 0 |
| Luna | Mark | 0 |
| Luna | John | 1 |
| Luke | Anthony | 0 |

Comment: What do you mean by "same value"? How do you decide that the same value is John and not Mario or Anthony?

Comment: What I want is how to find the user author that has the same connection with the user retweeted screen name. Or you could say that every user in the author column who has the same retweet of a tweet from the user's source in the retweeted_screen_name column. Suppose users A, B, C (authors) have something in common where they both retweet a tweet of user D (retweeted_screen_name) then assign a value of 1, if they have no connection or similarity then give a value of 0.

Comment: Please expand your example. It is still unclear. What should the "Label" column be if you have multiple common values? For example,  `[["Alice", "John"], ["Sandy", "John"], ["Alice", "Mark"], ["Luna", "Mark"]]`? Alice and Sandy have John in common and Alice and Luna have Mark in common

Comment: yes more or less as you described

Comment: That column label is actually what I want to create, so I'll give you an example of what I want the label to look like. So, for example, in the retweeted screen name column, the same name appears more than 1 time even though the same name is paired with a different name in the author column, the value is 1. Because the focus is on the retweeted_scree_name column. Labels based on whether there are similarities in retweeted_scr between user authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try with `groupby`:

```
df["Label"] = (df.groupby("RT_Screen_Name")["Author"].transform("count")>1).astype(int)

>>> df
  Author RT_Screen_Name  Label
0  Alice           John      1
1  Sandy           John      1
2   Lisa          Mario      0
3   Luna           Mark      0
4   Luna           John      1
5   Luke        Anthony      0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Label']=0
df.loc[df["RT_Screen_Name"]=="John", ["Label"]] = 1
```

It is unclear what condition you are using to decide the label variable, but if you are clear on your condition you can change out the conditional statement within this code. Also if you edit your question to clarify the condition, notify me and I will adjust my answer.

Comment: I want to do it not with condition, because in my dataset that have username in retweeted_screen_name column quite a lot. What I want is how to find the user author that has the same connection with the user retweeted screen name. Or you could say that every user in the author column who has the same retweet of a tweet from the user's source in the retweeted_screen_name column. Suppose users A, B, C (authors) have something in common where they both retweet a tweet of user D (retweeted_screen_name) then assign a value of 1, if they have no connection or similarity then give a value of 0.